# How will new 404 not found indexed pages affect rankings?

Tags: seo, http-status-code-404, web-crawler, googlebot

We had a situation where all of our page links were crawled and continue to be crawled.  The page links contain "~/{someTerm}/{someOtherTerm}/__p/##/##".

The problem is that now both Google and MSN bots are crawling tens of thousands of pages that don't need to be crawled and causing a strain on the system.

So we changed the paging link to a Javascript link, and removed all URL's containing "__p" so they will now return a 404 - Page Not Found.  We only really want page 1 indexed, and maybe a page or two thereafter (but not worried about that now.

Is there a way to remove all pages containing "__p" in the URL using WebMasterTools for Google and MSNBot, and if so, how?

Thanks.

Comment: Use a robots text file to define what is off limits: http://www.robotstxt.org/

Comment: In that case, would "Disallow: /*__p" in robots.txt do the trick?

Comment: I would use `/*__p$` to make it explicit that it lies at the end of the path, but yeah, that should do it. NOTE: The wildcard will work for Microsoft and Google, but potentially not all crawlers (of those who respect a standard robots.txt)

Comment: Probably only majors crawlers support wildcards. Use meta tag for all others if you can edit these pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use a `<meta>` tag in those pages you'd like to remove from search engines.

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />
```

Also, you can try out using robots.txt exclusion, look at this [site](http://www.robotstxt.org/orig.html)

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /*___p
```

Comment: Agreed, if the meta tag can be added to these pages it is much more ideal as all crawlers can understand that.